# How to select change particular variable in mapping?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I click button, I can see the "test" has updated in the console, however, it doesn't re-render since the test.map doesn't show the update. Is there anything I did wrong? Below is my code. Thanks a lot!

```
import { useState } from "react";

export function Table() {
    const button = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    const [test, setTest] = useState(['false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false'])
    function clickAction(id: number) {
        const newArray = test;
        newArray[id] = 'true';
        setTest(newArray);
        console.log(test)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {button.map((b, i) => {
                return (
                    <button key={i} onClick={() => { clickAction(i) }}>{`${b}`}</button>
                )
            })}
            {test.map((a, i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={i}>{a}</div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in functional React you are advised to use hooks. Here you should use `useCallback` hook.

```
const clickAction = useCallback((id: number) => {
    const newArray = test;
    newArray[id] = 'true';
    setTest(newArray);
    console.log(test);
}, [test]);
```

Second of all the `useState` hook does not work well with arrays and objects, you should destruct it:

```
setTest([...newArray]);
```